# Efficient way of finding nodes an unknown distance away, using cypher in Neo4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Say I have have matched a start node and now have its id.

Next I want to find all the nodes along incoming paths to my start node that have a certain label. I don't know how "distant" nodes with that label are (but think they will be less than 20 nodes away). If there *are* any related nodes with that label, they will all be the same distance away.

At the moment I'm doing:

```
MATCH (l:`mylabel`)-[*1..20]->(start) where id(start) = 1016236 RETURN l
```

But I'm guessing this could potentially be wasteful and inefficient and slow.

I could do something like (in psuedo code):

```
for $i in (1..20) {
    @ls = run_cypher("MATCH (l:`mylabel`)-[*1..$i]->(start) where id(start) = 1016236 RETURN l")
    last if @ls
}
```

But that needs multiple separate queries and is still wasteful.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Are you saying that if *any* path has node(s) with that label, then *all* paths will have node(s) with that label, and in exactly the same positions?

Comment: I was wrong (see comments on Brians answer)

Comment: Actually, if there are multiple depths, I only want nodes at the lowest depth

Comment: Can you share more about the model that you are querying? Unless your graph is very unusual (or unprecedentedly large) it's unlikely that you will get anything useful out of a depth-20 traversal. You are almost certainly traversing the entire graph.

Comment: I'm expecting long linear chains. I have (non-literal) parent->child relationships with the possibility of many "generations", and my starting point would be an unknown generation and I want to walk the tree from some child up to a certain ancestor. Unfortunately things are more complex and there isn't always just a single path to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If they're all going to be at the same depth you might do a query to find with a `LIMIT 1` and then query at that depth:

```
MATCH path=shortestPath((l:`mylabel`)-[*1..20]->(start))
WHERE id(start) = 1016236
RETURN min(length(rels(path))) AS min_depth
```

and then you could use that depth to query like this:

```
MATCH path=(l:`mylabel`)-[*$i..$i]->(start)
WHERE id(start) = 1016236
RETURN l
```

I'd be curious to know if that performs better.  Honestly since Neo4j is optimized for graph traversals it might not make a big difference, but it depends on your graph.  How well is it performing now?

Comment: Performance with my simple *1..20 is unsabaly bad: 75 seconds to return, vs ~instant if I use the correct depth once I know it (*1..6 in this case).

Comment: Your suggestion returns in less than a second, but with the wrong answer - it gives 10. (*10..10) returns the same nodes as (*6..6), so evendently there's 2 paths to my nodes, and I'm being told the longer one. (*10..10) is a touch slower than the ~instant (*6..6), so if there's a way to get the smallest depth that would be great...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The nodes at depth 6 and 10 are different. Not sure what to do now...

Comment: Actually, if there are multiple depths, I only want nodes at the lowest depth. So any thoughts on how to get the smallest depth quickly?

Comment: Or instead of smallest, how can I exclude paths that contain a node with a certain label (or a relationship of a certain type)?

Comment: Interesting, if you're talking about 75 seconds then it may be worth trying a query for each depth until you hit it and using `$i..$i` instead of `1..$i` from your original example.  You could change the first query to get a `min(length(..))` but that would look at all paths still.  If you could tell cypher to do a breadth first search that would solve it I think, but I don't think that's possible.  I'll ask some colleagues, though and see

Comment: If you're comfortable with Java you can also write an unmanaged extension which will let you write a custom search method for better performance, even if it's just to find that initial depth: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html

Comment: I'm told that using the `shortestPath` method will be more efficient because it doesn't go beyond the shortest depth that it's found as it's searching, so it should avoid a lot of paths.  I updated my answer to reflect that so give it a try

Comment: Your updated version with shortestPath takes 5-10 seconds; better, but still slower than doing my loop from 1 to 6 until I find some nodes via 6 separate queries.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response.  What about taking your very first query and using `allShortestPaths` to return all `l` results for everything that has the same shortest path length?